# Getting error in NetBeans "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Date" for Java class I am trying to test

Tags: java, netbeans

Getting error in NetBeans "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Date" for Java class I am trying to test. I am not sure what I have done wrong. I imported the date object thinking that would get me the output I desired. The error resides in the very bottom method where I am trying to test. Can anyone give any suggestions? Please see full code below:

```
package AmusementParkProgrammingProject;

import java.util.*;

import java.util.Date;

//Ticket class models admission tickets

public class Ticket          {

    //Instance Variables   
    private final long number;
    private final String category;
    private final String holder;
    private final Date date;
    private double price;
    private boolean purchased;


    // Constructor Ticket
    public Ticket (long number, String category, String holder, Date date, 
                   double price, boolean purchased)
    {      
        this.number = number;               
        this.category = category;            

        this.holder = holder;               
        this.date = date;                   
        this.price = price;                 
        this.purchased = purchased;        
    }


    // setPrice Mutator Method   
    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }  


    //setchangePurchaseStatus Mutator Method  
    public void setchangePurchaseStatus(boolean newStatus)
    {
        this.purchased = newStatus;
    } 


    //getnumber Accessor Method
    public long getnumber()
    {
        return number;
    }


    //getcategory Accessor Method
    public String getcategory()
    {
        return category;
    }


    //getholder Accessor Method
    public String getholder()
    {
        return holder;
    }


    //getdate Accessor Method
    public Date getdate()
    {
        return date;
    }


    //getprice Accessor Method
    public double getprice()
    {
        return price;
    }


    //getpurchased Accessor Method
    public boolean getpurchased()
    {
        return purchased;
    }

    // toString Method...............................
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return("Ticket Number:" + "\t" + this.number + "\n" + "Ticket Category:" 
        + "\t" + this.category + "\n" 
        + "Ticket Holder:" + "\t" + this.holder + "\n" + "Ticket Date:" + "\t" + 
        this.date + "\n" + "Ticket Price:" + "\t" + "$" + this.price + "\n" 
        + "Ticket Purchased" + "\t" + this.purchased + "\n");
    }

    // Added method to test Ticket class
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Ticket _t = new Ticket(23456, "adult", "Erin", 10-22-17, 20.0, true);
        System.out.println(_t);    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also instead use

```
Ticket _t = new Ticket(23456, "adult", "Erin", new Date(2017,10,22), 20.0, true);
```

See [Date Java Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Comment: Thankyou! This also did not allow my program to return any output. How do I make it return the output I desire?

Answer (score 0):

The defect is in `main`, you can't declare a `Date` instance with integer math. This

```
Ticket _t = new Ticket(23456, "adult", "Erin", 10-22-17, 20.0, true);
```

should be something like

```
try {
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy").parse("10-22-17");
    Ticket _t = new Ticket(23456, "adult", "Erin", d, 20.0, true);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Elliot, this allowed my file to compile successfully, but it did not return any output. I need to make sure I can get the output that is called in the string.